# Couldnt install pymongo==4.3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My Ubuntu server had python 2.7.17 as default. When i try to install **pymongo==4.3.3**,prompt an error to upgrade python version to 3. Then i install python3 and set as default version. All commands i executed as root.Then i check python version using `python --version` and as root i can see python 3.10 set as default version. But as a normal user i can see old version is default version.Also till get same error for pymongo installation.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymongo==4.3.3 (from versions: 0.1rc0, 0.1.1rc0, 0.1.2rc0, 0.2rc0, 0.3rc0, 0.3.1rc0, 0.4rc0, 0.5rc0, 0.5.1rc0, 0.5.2rc0, 0.5.3rc0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.9.7, 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.11, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 0.15, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16, 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.9, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.11, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.3, 2.4, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.5, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.6, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.7, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.8, 2.8.1, 2.9, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.9.4, 2.9.5, 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.4.0, 3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.8.0, 3.9.0, 3.10.0, 3.10.1, 3.11.0, 3.11.1, 3.11.2, 3.11.3, 3.11.4, 3.12.0, 3.12.1, 3.12.2, 3.12.3, 3.13.0)
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Well, that's to be expected because you're not always the root user. This is why virtual environments exist

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two versions of python installed you need to be specific when installing any library.
Try this:

```
python3.10 -m pip install pymongo==4.3.3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and i tried it then got that kind of error. ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 146, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip.```

Comment: Is this the entire error it spitted out?

Comment: Couldnt post entire error. will add full error as portion in few comments. ```_vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)```

Comment: ```File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked```

Comment: ```File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 632, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 943, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping```

Comment: This is entire error.

Comment: Perhaps the version of pymongo you are trying to install with python 3.10 are not compatible. however, I can not make sense of your traceback error. Edit your question and and the entire traceback to form part of your question.

Comment: Another fix you may try is to not specify the pymongo version except you are particular about this version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253028/discussion-between-nelsonsule-and-kavindu).

Comment: Added reply in in chat.

Comment: Uninstalled python3 and reinstalled, then i can install pymongo successfullly.